# When should we prefer rounded corner rectangle over square corner rectangle?

Tags: gui-design, interface

I always find myself in a dilemma about whether to choose rounded corners or square corners, for both applications UI & web design.

As I read in a couple of articles choose one style of corners and stick to it throughout the project.

I am new into interface designing.

Answer (score 2):

I don't entirely agree with the concept that you have to use exclusively on style of corner throughout your app. I think it depends on what you're trying to accomplish with your design.

For example, rounded corners are very popular on input boxes and site-level wrappers. They lend a nice, smooth appearance that is appealing to users and has a sleek, modern feel. However, that same site could have a layout of card structures linking to various parts of the site. Coupled with a subtle box shadow, this can be a nice analog that is very intuitive to users with the bonus of being visually appealing.

**The bottom line boils down to opinion.** Rarely do corner styles play a large role in usability of a site which, in my humble opinion, should always take priority when designing an application, be it web or native. Do what makes the most sense to you as long as you're sure it won't negatively impact your user's experience.

Comment: Look at this site- the nav buttons and search box use sharp corners but the header box that overlaps the blue UX banner has rounded top corners. I think it looks great, but I bet sharp corners would look great too. I agree with SethG that this is a question of _aesthetics_ not as much _usability_.